# Is my hiragana readable?

Tags: hiragana

I've just started learning Japanese and I decided to learn hiragana and katakana before proceeding because I want to stay away from rōmaji. How is my hiragana handwriting? Is it readable? Any suggestions for improvement are welcome. 
[image: hiragana chart]

[image: some examples... I found the sentence online]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the (il)legibility of your handwriting does not help the community at large.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that tinkle me a bit is that sometimes your stroke should be more straight. In the first picture your **ほ** might look like **しま** to me. Same for **に** on the second picture, in the second sentence. It might look like a **しこ**.
Besides that, I think your writing is very readable, congratulations !

Answer (score 1):

also, is it my imagination or did you write your "ne" ね　using 3 pen strokes? It looks as though you might have written a horizontal dash - followed by a vertical line | followed by  the curled part, when you are supposed 'zig-zag' through the vertical line without lifting your pencil. It looks like you did it correctly with れ in the top paper. (Though I see the れ in the bottom paper looks like 3 lines, again....)